# Why is the function make_response in flask python file app.py having an argument rv equalling zero?

Tags: python, html, flask, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to take some input number from a flask website and then plug those numbers into a neural network, which stores the outputs on a dictionary. Then, I have a result page which has a table with all the outputs on them.
Here is all the relevant flask code:

```
@app.route('/ConvNet', methods=["GET", "POST"])

def ConvNet():
    return render_template("ConvNet.html")

@app.route('/ConvNetForm', methods=["GET", "POST"])

def ConvNetForm():
    if request.form == "POST":
         #hyperparameters
        learning_rate = request.form['learning_rate']
        training_iters= request.form['training_iters']
        batch_size= request.form['batch_size']
        display_step = request.form['display_step']

        #network parameters
        #28 * 28 image
        n_input = 784
        n_classes = 10
        dropout = 0.75

        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, n_input])
        y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, n_classes])
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

        def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
            x = tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding = 'SAME')
            x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
            return tf.nn.relu(x)

        def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
            return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,k,k,1], strides=[1,k,k,1], padding='SAME')

        #create model
        def conv_net(x, weights, biases, dropout):
            #reshape input
            x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

            #convolutional layer
            conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
            #maxpooling
            conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

            conv2 = conv2d( conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
            conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

            fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
            fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
            fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
            #apply dropout
            fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

            #outpout, class predication
            out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
            return out

        #create weights
        weights = {
                'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32])),
                'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,64])),
                'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024])),
                'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))
        }

        biases = {
                'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
                'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
                'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
                'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
          }

        #construct model
        pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)

        #define optimizer and loss
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = pred,labels = y))
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

        #Evaluate model
        correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

        #initializing the variables
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

        style.use('fivethirtyeight')

        #Creating Graph
        #fig = plt.figure(edgecolor='c')
        #ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

        ConvResult=dict()
        # Launch the graph
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(init)
            step = 1
            # Keep training until reach max iterations
            while step * batch_size < training_iters:
                images_seen = step * batch_size
                batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                # Run optimization op (backprop)
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                               keep_prob: dropout})
                if step % display_step == 0:
                    # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
                    loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                                      y: batch_y,
                                                                      keep_prob: 1.})
                    print("Iter " + str(images_seen) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                          "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                          "{:.5f}".format(acc))
                    ConvResult[images_seen] = acc
                step += 1
            print("Optimization Finished!")

            # Calculate accuracy for 256 mnist test images
            print("Testing Accuracy:", \
                sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[:256],
                                              y: mnist.test.labels[:256],
                                              keep_prob: 1.}))
        return render_template("ConvNetForm.html", ConvResult=ConvResult)
```

Here is all the relevant html code:(templates)

```
{% extends "header.html" %}
{% block body %}
<h1 class="text-center">Convolutional Neural Network Site</h1>
<div class="title">
    <h3>Post Hyper Parameter Values</h3>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('ConvNetForm')}}">
        <label for="learning_rate">Please enter a value for the hyper parameter learning rate:</label>
        <input type="number" name="learning_rate" value="0.001" step="0.001" min="0"max="1"/><br />
        <label for="training_iters">Please enter a value for the hyper parameter training iterations:</label>
        <input type="number" name="training_iters" value="200000" min="1000" max="500000"/><br />
        <label for="batch_size">Please enter a value for the hyper parameter batch size:</label>
        <input type="number" name="batch_size" value="128" min="1" max="1000"/><br />
        <label for="display_step">Please enter a value for the hyper parameter display step:</label>
        <input type="number" name="display_step" value="10" min="1" max="100"/><br />
        <input type="submit" />
        <input type="reset" />
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And relevant code from result template:

```
{% extends "header.html" %}
{% block body %}

<h1 class="text-center">Results of Convolutional Neural Network</h1>
<table>
{% for key, value in ConvResult.iteritems() %}
    <tr>
        <th> {{ key }} </th>
        <td> {{ value }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Also, the actual error on the computer was value error: view function did not return a response.

Comment: What happen with `request.form = "GET"` in `ConvNetForm` function?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should have changed the methods allowed to only post on the form and not even mention the methods on the convnet function.